# Sonarqube on different country

Tags: sonarqube

I have a question about how to proceed for a better configuration of Sonarqube / Mysql.
I'm using Sonarqube with Mysql on a server in USA and we have servers that will proceed with the code analysis in Europe. The Jenkins server is in US but the slave in Europe.

The code analysis takes a lot of time for transferring data from EU to US and I suppose that is related to Mysql transference between countries.

We have decided to create a new Sonarqube instance in Europe for reporting those projects, but we prefer keeping all the projects together in US.

How can we proceed for a faster analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you decided is the best option for the moment.

You can watch and vote for [SONAR-2119](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2119): "Separate Sonar Analysis from Database Update". Indeed, this is what will help having far better performances when the analyses happen far from the DB. We have started doing the internal refactoring to achieve this goal, and hopefully we'll be able to achieve this in a couple of versions.